# Map over Javascript array and transform objects in it to a specific format?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have an array of objects

```
const mainArray = [{
    name: 'main name',
    id: 'main id',
    parent: [{
      name: 'parent name',
      id: '1'
    }],
    child: [{
      name: 'child name',
      id: 'child id'
    }]
  }, {
    name: 'main name 2',
    id: 'main id 2',
    parent: [{
      name: 'parent name',
      id: '1'
    }],
    child: [{
      name: 'child name 2',
      id: 'child id 2'
    }]
  },
  {
    name: 'main name 3',
    id: 'main id 3',
    parent: [{
      name: 'parent name something else',
      id: '2'
    }],
    child: [{
      name: 'child name 3',
      id: 'child id 3'
    }]
  }
]
```

I need to bring it to this form

```
const resultArray = [{
  key: 'main',
  title: 'main name',
}, {
  key: 'parent',
  title: 'parent name'
}, {
  key: 'child',
  title: 'child name'
}]
```

So far I got this

```
if (mainArray) {
   mainArray.map((main) => {
     if (main.child && main.child.length) {
       if (main.parent && main.parent.length) {
         main.parent.map((item) => {
           data.push({
             key: 'parent',
             title: item.name
           });
         });
       }

       data.push({
         key: 'main',
         title: main.name
       });

       main.child.map((item) => {
         data.push({
           key: 'child',
           title: item.name
         });
       });
     }
   });
 }
```

And then I take this `data array` to display if a table and it looks like this

[image]

My problem is - two `mains` can be different but have the same `parent` (parents have the same `ids`) and then I don't need to add the parent to array two times, and I need it to be displayed like this

[image]

So I'm looking to a way to if two `parents` objects have the same `id` to merge them together so that in the final array there will be only one `parent` and the `main` and the `child` of that parent get stuck to one `parent` instead of two identical ones

Here the [link](https://jsfiddle.net/4evnd1f0/1/) to jsfiddle

I can use **lodash**

Comment: please add the result, you want from the given data.

Comment: This is not a map operation. You do not return anything from the inner function and you ignore the result. So I think there is no point on using the map function. Use forEach. It fits much better with the rest of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could first group by parent and return an object where each key is parent name, then from that object you can create an array.

```js
const mainArray = [{"name":"main name","id":"main id","parent":[{"name":"parent name","id":"1"}],"child":[{"name":"child name","id":"child id"}]},{"name":"main name 2","id":"main id 2","parent":[{"name":"parent name","id":"1"}],"child":[{"name":"child name 2","id":"child id 2"}]},{"name":"main name 3","id":"main id 3","parent":[{"name":"parent name something else","id":"2"}],"child":[{"name":"child name 3","id":"child id 3"}]}]


function children(rest, child) {
  const result = [{
    key: 'main',
    title: rest.name
  }];
  result.push(...child.map(({
    name
  }) => ({
    key: 'child',
    title: name
  })))
  return result;
}

const groupByParent = mainArray.reduce((r, {
  parent,
  child,
  ...rest
}) => {
  parent.forEach(p => {
    if (!r[p.name]) {
      r[p.name] = [{
          key: 'parent',
          title: p.name
        },
        ...children(rest, child)
      ]
    } else {
      r[p.name].push(...children(rest, child));
    }
  })

  return r;
}, {})

const result = Object.values(groupByParent).flat()
console.log(result)
```

Comment: This helped a lot, thank you. Can you please explain why do we need to user spread when we pushing ```child``` to ```result``` ```result.push(...child.map(({...```?

Comment: Because map returns an array and you want to push each object not an array.